# Codeigniter rest server 500 error after uploading to hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest, codeigniter-3

My codeigniter 3 application uses rest server. My application is working locally and when i uploaded application works except post end points of rest server routes gives 500 error but nothing on error log file.

Server uses

```
PHP 5.3.28 (cli) (built: Dec 17 2013 00:28:38)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

and server is `Linux 3.2.28-45.63.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64`

I use 5.3 in my ampps setup. In local setup everything works fine.

routes files has custom routes

```
$route['api/subscription/notify'] = 'api/subscription/notify'; 
$route['api/ussd/receiver'] = 'api/ussd/receiver';
```

Add Subscription.php and USSD resides in api folder inside controllers folder.

I use `.htaccess` file to remove `index.php` from URLS.

it's

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|imapp|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And

`$config['index_page'] = '';`

Is set like this in `config.php`

Comment: but nothing on error log file.

Comment: I have set log threshold to 1 @Fred-ii-

Comment: maybe you're not checking the right log file

Comment: 500 is usually server side, not PHP. Check apache error log.

Comment: In this server setup is a shared server space I do not had access to Apache log files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the error. Rest Server is needed PHP5.4 or higher since it uses ne array [] format. So help of some other repo in Github I was able to make it compatible with PHP 5.3.